# Invariant measure of Lorentz Group

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups

If I decompose a general element $\Lambda$ of the proper Lorentz group as
$$
\Lambda=R(\alpha,\beta,0)\,L_3(\xi)\,R(\phi,\theta,\psi)^{-1},
$$
where $R$ are rotation matrices and $L_3$ is a boost along the z-axis, can I obtain the **invariant measure** of the group by multiplying the invariant measures of rotations and boost?
Thanks for your help.